# str.replace is not a function in ember 2.1.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Upgrading Ember project from

*Ember.js 1.13.7*

*Ember-data 1.13.7*

**to**

*Ember.js 2.1.0*

*Ember-data 2.1.0*

Getting Following Error

> TypeError: str.replace is not a function

model (trends.js)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name:DS.attr('string',{defaultValue:''}),
    daterangekey:DS.attr('number',{defaultValue:0}),
    daterange:DS.attr(),
    actiondata:DS.attr(),
    criteria:DS.attr('string',{defaultValue:function(){
        return [];
    }}),
    unit:DS.attr('number',{defaultValue:1}),
    viewtype:DS.attr('number',{defaultValue:3})
});
```

Route (trends.js)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model:function()
    {
        return this.store.findAll('trend');
    },
});
```

payload returning form server is

```
{"trends":[{"viewtype":3,"name":"Trend A","daterangekey":0,"type":1,"unit":1,"actiondata":[{"label":"action 2","id":3}],"criteria":[],"id":"1000000000027"}]}
```

I'm really trying to wrap my head around EmberJS but I've been stuck here on this for the last two days!

Thanks

**Edited**

model (trends.js)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name:DS.attr('string',{defaultValue:''}),
    daterangekey:DS.attr('number',{defaultValue:0}),
    daterange:DS.attr(),
    actiondata:DS.attr(),
    criteria:DS.attr({defaultValue:function(){
        return [];
    }}),
    unit:DS.attr('number',{defaultValue:1}),
    viewtype:DS.attr('number',{defaultValue:3})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `"type":1`  from the payload. Its bug in ember-data and it has been fixed in [1.13.12 release](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#release-11312-september-10-2015).
https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3725

Comment: Thanks @kumkanillam

Comment: I have upgraded to ember 2.1.0. . so this bug should not be for this version right.?

Comment: @dilipkumar Upgrading ember-data >= 1.13.12 will fix this error. by the way you haven't defined `type` attribute for `trend` model, then why do you need send it in payload.

Answer (score 0):

`criteria` is an array but you define it as string.

Change like this :

```
criteria:DS.attr({defaultValue:function(){
        return [];
    }}),
```

Comment: I changed it as you have mentioned but still same error populating. Thanks